# google pie chart show slice text outside for small slices

Tags: javascript, visualization, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

I'm using google charts, and I want to show the pie slice text for the small slices without rotating the pie chart (chart should not be rotated).

Is it possible to show pie slice text outside the pie only for small slices(similar to charts in MS Excel as shown in below image), remaining should display the slice text within the slice itself.[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: no standard option for this...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for the reply.. any add-ons we can write ?? any hint ??

Comment: sure, wait for the `'ready'` event to fire, use method to find slice placement --> `chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox('slice#0')` -- draw text box with line using coords given -- you'll need to leave room in the `chartArea` to allow for additional drawing -- but if you're planning to use the `getImageURI` method -- changes will most likely not be represented there...

Comment: [here is an example of drawing text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41857399/5090771) using the _Layout Interface_ -- here, annotations are added to the CandleStick chart, which it doesn't support...

Comment: @WhiteHat I want to convert the chart as image once it's drawn.  Unfortunately am using "my_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + my_chart.getImageURI() + '">'; to do that.. So, it means it's not possible ?

Comment: yes, i just tested the example provided above, annotations added do not appear in the image -- could be because i don't know enough about svg -- but probably because the same code used to draw builds the image...

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks a lot :) will check in that perspective...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this: [fiddler Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wkdrzgzu/)

use legend property `legend: {position: 'labeled'}`

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Activities',
       legend: {position: 'labeled'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: No, brother. This will result in legends getting displayed along with slice text. I don't want to disturb the legends.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and my solution is put the number at the end of each legend.

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work (11)',     11],
      ['Eat (2)',      2],
      ['Commute (2)',  2],
      ['Watch TV (2)', 2],
      ['Sleep (7)',    7]
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Activities',
        legend: {position: 'right'}
    };
```