# Google chart - role: annotation in candlestick bar

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, candlestick-chart

I try to add ({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}) to candlestick bar. But annotation doesnt show. Any advice ?

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 

data.addColumn('string', 'label');
data.addColumn('number', '');  
data.addColumn('number', '');  
data.addColumn('number', '');  
data.addColumn('number', ''); 
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});  
data.addRows([
    ['Test1', 55,55,66,66,'test1'],
    ['Test1', 66,66,77,77,'test2'],
    ['Test1', 88,88,-99,-99,'test3'],
    ['Test1', -99,-99,66,66,'test4'],
]);   
var options = {
  ..
}
```

Comment: [CandlestickChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#data-format) does not support annotations, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41857399/5090771) for adding your own...

Comment: aah, its works, but i try it in IE and there is "magic" problem. http://imgur.com/a/gb3eW i wrote annotation.innerHTML via console.log and its fine but in chart is strange output

Comment: thanks! made edit to that answer, corrected using jquery -- IE does not support `innerHTML` on svg elements...

Comment: also, if you plan on using chart method `getImageURI`, annotations will not show...

Comment: Thx, for your edit. Its funny :) i use getImageURI for other charts :) now i search for another way how get svg to png :)